# Why patch linux kernel on Centos for using Docker.io

Tags: linux, deployment, continuous-integration, docker, lxc

I'm trying to shift my applications to a more formalised deployment method like using Docker.io, but as I checked on how it works, it relies on a patched linux kernel. So I'm wondering what such patch is it? What uncertainty it brings if I move my whole architect to go with this patched kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, Docker requires:

- a recent enough kernel (>= 3.8) - older versions might misbehave
- cgroups and namespace support enabled
- AUFS support built-in

Ubuntu and Debian default kernel are ok, although Red Hat (and derivative) don't seem to ship AUFS by default.

So what you have to do kernel-wise should sum-up to: build with AUFS (see http://aufs.sourceforge.net/). There seem to exist various tutorials on the web for Centos/Docker, with instructions about the EPEL repository and AUFS support.

More informations about Docker kernel requirements:
http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/kernel/

Also note that the AUFS requirement will possibly/probably (?) be dropped in future docker versions, and be replaced by something else.

Finally, about the "uncertainty" this brings to your architecture: I don't think having AUFS support should be a cause for much worry - but you will have to investigate that.
About the "uncertainty" that using docker brings, I think it boils down more to the uncertainty that **lxc** brings. You should probably read about linux containers generally if you want to fully understand the implications (possibly https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html)

Disclaimer: I'm not a Centos user.

Comment: Very complete answer; and I would like to add that AUFS requirement should indeed be dropped in Docker 0.7, which will use device-mapper thin provisioned snapshots instead. Those snapshots will be compatible with Red Hat kernels (since this feature has been ported to the RHEL kernels used in RH 6.5 and even possibly RH 6.4).

Comment: To confirm, one month after @jpetazzo's comment Docker 0.7 was released and the AUFS requirement was definitely dropped. As of 0.7 a storage driver API is used for copy-on-write instead and it comes with a few drivers, one of which is called "devicemapper"; this is the one used to get copy-on-write working with RHEL.  http://blog.docker.io/2013/11/docker-0-7-docker-now-runs-on-any-linux-distribution/